# How to annotate type objects of all classes, subclassed from a specified base type in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a base class:

```
class FooBase:
    pass
```

And I have some subclasses of it:

```
class Bar(FooBase): pass
class Baz(FooBase): pass
class Quux(FooBase): pass
```

I need a data structure to hold one and only one instance of some of these subclasses. I preferred to use dictionaries because it simplifies code and enhances performance:

```
ds = {}
ds[Bar] = Bar()
ds[Quux] = Quux()
```

My question is how to annotate this data structure:

```
ds: dict[Any, FooBase] = {}
```

What must I put in place of `Any` that means a `type` object of any subclass of `FooBase`?

Comment: `type[FooBase]`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#the-type-of-class-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on whether you want the class used as a key to exactly match the type of instance stored as the corresponding value.

If you *don't*, then this is sufficient: (as mentioned by @jonrsharpe in the comments)

```py
ds: dict[type[FooBase], FooBase] = {}
```

But it will mean the following are all type safe:

```py
ds[Baz] = Baz()
ds[Bar] = Quux()
ds[FooBase] = Bar()
```

---

If you want the value types to match those of the keys, you will need to put in some more work. I don't think there is a way to express that a `dict` should enforce this constraint.

But you can create your own class that *emulates* a [`MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) (behaves similarly to a regular `dict`), but indicates to type checkers that key and value types must match. To do that you need to define a [*constrained* type variable](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics) with all your `FooBase` subtypes.

You can then implement the mutable mapping methods `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` as *generic* functions and annotate the relevant parameters with that constrained type variable:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator
from typing import TypeVar, cast

T = TypeVar("T", Bar, Baz, Quux)


class ClassDict:
    _mapping: dict[type[FooBase], FooBase]

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._mapping = {}

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._mapping)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[type[FooBase]]:
        return iter(self._mapping)

    # ... any other relevant methods like `__contains__`, `keys`, `__eq__`, etc.

    def __getitem__(self, key: type[T]) -> T:
        return cast(T, self._mapping[key])

    def __setitem__(self, key: type[T], value: T) -> None:
        self._mapping[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key: type[T]) -> None:
        del self._mapping[key]
```

Usage:

```py
ds = ClassDict()
ds[Bar] = Bar()          # passes
ds[Baz] = Baz()          # passes
ds[Quux] = Quux()        # passes
ds[Bar] = Baz()          # error
ds[Quux] = Baz()         # error
ds[FooBase] = FooBase()  # error

bar = ds[Bar]
baz = ds[Baz]
quux = ds[Quux]
reveal_type(bar)   # inferred as Bar
reveal_type(baz)   # inferred as Baz
reveal_type(quux)  # inferred as Quux

del ds[Bar]      # passes
del ds[FooBase]  # error
```

You can try it out in [this Mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=1e14a3b274fdd71642a490fb54b4e12b).

---

**Note**: Unfortunately you cannot simply subclass [`collections.abc.MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) in a type safe way because those generic methods for getting, setting and deleting items would violate the [lsp](/questions/tagged/lsp) by narrowing their parameter types.

But if you are willing to compromise on that bit of type safety you can inherit from `MutableMapping[type[FooBase], FooBase]` and use `type: ignore[override]` directives for those affected methods. The benefit is that you get those mixed in methods like `get`, `items`, `__contains__` etc. automatically, i.e. you won't need to implement them yourself. See [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) for details.

Alternatively you could inherit from `MutableMapping[Any, FooBase]`. This may be the best compromise because you would get the benefits of the ABC without having to use `# type: ignore` directives. However the `Any` key type argument is somewhat of a cheat of course because it will by definition pass all type checks.

That is not to say you will lose those key-value-matching constraints. The *methods* would still look the same and also enforce those constraints the same way. Just the `ClassDict` type as a whole would pass any type check for mutable mappings as long as the value type matches.

It would look like this:

```py
...

class ClassDict(MutableMapping[Any, FooBase]):
    _mapping: dict[type[FooBase], FooBase]

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._mapping = {}

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._mapping)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[type[FooBase]]:
        return iter(self._mapping)

    def __getitem__(self, key: type[T]) -> T:
        return cast(T, self._mapping[key])

    def __setitem__(self, key: type[T], value: T) -> None:
        self._mapping[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key: type[T]) -> None:
        del self._mapping[key]
```

And the consequence would be this:

```py
x: MutableMapping[int, Any] = ClassDict()      # passes
y: MutableMapping[int, FooBase] = ClassDict()  # passes
z: MutableMapping[int, str] = ClassDict()      # error
```

Notice how the `int` key type does not cause any issue. Maybe someone has an even better solution, but it seems you will have to compromise one way or another.